# Creating a document full of images with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to use google apps script to make a google document full of images with the name of the image beneath each one.  All of the images are in a google drive folder.
Here is what I have tried:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('This document is a test');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  var folderID = 'FOLDER_ID_HERE';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  
  var file;
  
  while (contents.hasNext()){
    var file = contents.next();
    var name = file.getName();
    var url = file.getUrl();
    body.appendParagraph(name);
    //Add image to document here somehow???
  }
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

What's the correct way to load an image from file here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

The `body.appendImage(blob)` method appends an image converted as a blob into Google Docs. Note that the references I have included at the bottom includes methods to adjust the size of the inline image returned by the `appendImage()` function in case your images do not fit into the document.

### Sample Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('This document is a test');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  var folderID = 'FOLDER-ID-HERE';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var contents = folder.getFiles();

  while (contents.hasNext()){
    var file = contents.next();
    var name = file.getName();
    var url = file.getUrl();
    body.appendParagraph(name);
    body.appendImage(file.getBlob());
  }
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

### Sample Doc:

[image]

### References:

[appendImage()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendimageimage)

[Inline Images](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-image)